# jquery nestedSortable How to access current element className from _isAllowed

Tags: jquery, nested-sortable

I have required to extend jquery.nestedSortable to add some events inside _isAllowed and see that within that function, it's now supported to access parentItem, level and levels, but I have been struggling on accessing the current item. I need to check the current item li className.